# C++ Store How many days ago a date was in a Date object

Tags: c++, date, object

I am trying to store how many days ago a day is into an object in C++. The book says it's doing this way because C++ doesn't have a proper definition for date, or at least one that doesn't track days after 1970. I've been trying to follow a book in my leisure. The script starts off with taking three inputs, month, day, and year. It puts them through a constructor that adds a forth parameter, old, which defaults to 0.

After that my main program attempts to run a function to calculate how many days ago that day was using a pastDays function, part of a personally written Date class, and attempts to assign it to the forth parameter of old in an object.

Here we have the main.cpp / driver program. The constructor works and it creates objects of type Date.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Date.h" // Date class definition
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int birthMonth = 0;
    int birthDay = 0;
    int birthYear = 0;

    int dateToMonth = 0;
    int dateToDay = 0;
    int dateToYear = 0;

    cout << "Enter birth month (1-12): ";
    cin >> birthMonth;
    cout << "Enter birth day (1-31): ";
    cin >> birthDay;
    cout << "Enter birth year (1900 - 2000): ";
    cin >> birthYear;

    Date birthDate (birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear);

    cout << "To which date would you like to calculate to?\nEnter Day month (1-12): ";
    cin >> dateToMonth;
    cout << "Enter Day to calculate it to (1-31): ";
    cin >> dateToDay;
    cout << "Enter Year to calculate it to: ";
    cin >> dateToYear;

    Date dateTo (dateToMonth, dateToDay, dateToYear);

    Date d1( 12, 27, 2010, 0 ); // December 27, 2010
    Date d2; // defaults to January 1, 1900

    Date::pastDays(birthDate);
    Date::pastDays(dateTo);

    // birthDate = birthDate - dateTo;
    cout << birthDate.old;
}
```

When I attempt to use this, on...
    Date::pastDays(birthDate);
I get the error, "Cannot call member function 'int Date::pastDays(Date)' without object."

I seem to be passing the object through there.

Here is the Date.h header.

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class Date
  {
    friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &, const Date & );
public:
    Date( int m = 1, int d = 1, int y = 1900, int o = 0 ); // default constructor
    void setDate( int, int, int, int ); // set month, day, year
    Date &operator++(); // prefix increment operator
    Date operator++( int ); // postfix increment operator
    Date &operator+=( unsigned int ); // add days, modify object
    int pastDays (Date);
    static bool leapYear( int ); // is date in a leap year?
    bool endOfMonth( int ) const; // is date at the end of month?
    unsigned int month;
    unsigned int day;
    unsigned int year;
    int old;
    static const std::array< unsigned int, 13 > days; // days per month
    void helpIncrement(); // utility function for incrementing date
}; // end class Date

#endif
```

Here we have the main Date.cpp program. It starts by creating variables made to copy what the input day, month, and year are. I tried designing it so that pastDays takes that information, it decrements the day and month to Jan 1st, and stores it in the variable of daysAgo, the amount of negative days created.

Then it increments the year, and adds 365 or 366 depending on if it is a leap year or not. Then it increments the current day and month back up to the current day, adding the the changes back to the daysAgo variable. Then it tries to put that as the entryDay information, but in the old parameter, so that the original object now has that information filled out. At least that is the plan.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Date.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

   // initialize static member; one classwide copy
const array< unsigned int, 13 > Date::days = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

// Date constructor
Date::Date( int month, int day, int year, int old )
  {
    setDate( month, day, year, old );
  } // end Date constructor

// set month, day and year
void Date::setDate( int mm, int dd, int yy, int old )
  {
    if ( mm >= 1 && mm <= 12 )
        month = mm;
    else
        throw invalid_argument( "Month must be 1-12" );

    if ( yy >= 1900 && yy <= 2100 )
        year = yy;

    // test for a leap year
        if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12){
            if (dd >= 1 || dd <= 31)
            day == dd;
        }
        if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11){
            if (dd >= 1 || dd <= 30)
            day == dd;
        }
        if (month == 2)
            if ( year % 4 != 0 ) {
    if (dd >= 1 || dd <= 29)
    day == dd;
            }
        if (month == 2)
            if ( year % 4 != 0 ) {
    if (dd >= 1 || dd <= 28)
    day == dd;
            }
        else {
            throw invalid_argument(
    "Day is out of range for current month and year" );
        }
} // end function setDate

// overloaded prefix increment operator
Date &Date::operator++()
{
    helpIncrement(); // increment date
    return *this; // reference return to create an lvalue
} // end function operator++

// overloaded postfix increment operator; note that the
// dummy integer parameter does not have a parameter name
Date Date::operator++( int )
{
    Date temp = *this; // hold current state of object
    helpIncrement();

// return unincremented, saved, temporary object
    return temp; // value return; not a reference return
} // end function operator++

// add specified number of days to date
Date &Date::operator+=( unsigned int additionalDays )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < additionalDays; ++i )
        helpIncrement();
    return *this; // enables cascading
} // end function operator+=


Date pastDays (Date &entryDay) {
    //Creating Today date object
    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm * now = localtime(&t);
    int currentYear = now -> tm_year + 1900;
    int currentMonth = now -> tm_mon + 1;
    int currentDay = now -> tm_mday;

    int birthMonth = entryDay.month;
    int birthDay = entryDay.day;
    int birthYear = entryDay.year;

    //The variable that will be assigned to the old parameter, which can then be subtracted from another time.
    int daysAgo = 0;

    //Lowering days to 1, to make transition between years easier.
    while (birthDay > 1){
        birthDay--;
        daysAgo--;
    }

    cout << daysAgo;

    //Lowering months to 1, to make transition between years easier.
    while (birthMonth > 1){
        if (birthMonth == 1 || birthMonth == 3 || birthMonth == 5 || birthMonth == 7 || birthMonth == 8 || birthMonth == 10 || birthMonth == 12){
            birthMonth--;
            daysAgo -= 31;
        }
        if (birthMonth == 4 || birthMonth == 6 || birthMonth == 9 || birthMonth == 11){
            birthMonth--;
            daysAgo -= 30;
        }
        if (birthMonth == 2)
            if ( currentYear % 400 == 0 ||
            ( currentYear % 100 != 0 && currentYear % 4 == 0 ) ) {
    birthMonth--;
    daysAgo -= 29;
            }
        else {
            birthMonth--;
            daysAgo -= 28;
        }
    }


    cout << daysAgo;
    //Incrementing year to current year
    while (birthYear < currentYear){
        if ( currentYear % 400 == 0 ||
        ( currentYear % 100 != 0 && currentYear % 4 == 0 ) ) {
            daysAgo = daysAgo + 366;
            birthYear++;
        }
        else {
            daysAgo = daysAgo + 365;
            birthYear++;
        }
    }


    cout << daysAgo;
    // Incrementing to current month
    while (birthMonth < currentMonth) {
        if (birthMonth == 1 || birthMonth == 3 || birthMonth == 5 || birthMonth == 7 || birthMonth == 8 || birthMonth == 10 || birthMonth == 12){
            birthMonth++;
            daysAgo += 31;
        }
        if (birthMonth == 4 || birthMonth == 6 || birthMonth == 9 || birthMonth == 11){
            birthMonth++;
            daysAgo += 30;
        }
        if (birthMonth == 2)
            if ( currentYear % 400 == 0 ||
            ( currentYear % 100 != 0 && currentYear % 4 == 0 ) ) {
    birthMonth++;
    daysAgo += 29;
            }
        else {
            birthMonth++;
            daysAgo += 28;
        }
    }

    cout << daysAgo;
    //Incrementing to current day, and adding the days to the daysAgo
    while (birthDay < currentDay){
        birthDay++;
        daysAgo++;
    }



    cout << daysAgo;
    //Assigning DaysAgo to input parameter.old
    entryDay.old = daysAgo;
    return(entryDay);
}


// if the year is a leap year, return true; otherwise, return false
bool Date::leapYear( int testYear )
{
    if ( testYear % 400 == 0 ||
      ( testYear % 100 != 0 && testYear % 4 == 0 ) )
        return true; // a leap year
    else
        return false; // not a leap year
} // end function leapYear

// determine whether the day is the last day of the month
bool Date::endOfMonth( int testDay ) const
{
    if ( month == 2 && leapYear( year ) )
        return testDay == 29; // last day of Feb. in leap year
    else
        return testDay == days[ month ];
} // end function endOfMonth

// function to help increment the date
void Date::helpIncrement()
{
    // day is not end of month
    if ( !endOfMonth( day ) )
        ++day; // increment day
    else
        if ( month < 12 ) // day is end of month and month < 12
        {
            ++month; // increment month
            day = 1; // first day of new month
        } // end if
        else // last day of year
        {
            ++year; // increment year
            month = 1; // first month of new year
            day = 1; // first day of new month
        } // end else
} // end function helpIncrement

// overloaded output operator
ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const Date &d )
{
  static string monthName[ 13 ] = { "", "January", "February",
        "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
        "September", "October", "November", "December" };
  output << monthName[ d.month ] << ' ' << d.day << ", " << d.year;
  return output; // enables cascading
} // end function operator<<
```

My main issue is that I cannot calculate the days ago it was, and store it in the fourth Date parameter.

Dot
Dot
Dot
Dot
Dot

**After a few more hours, I have now modified the program to calculate how many days ago it has been. I am listing it here for others to see. Perhaps it shall help others.**

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>
#include "Date.cpp" // Date class definition
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned int birthMonth = 0;
    unsigned int birthDay = 0;
    unsigned int birthYear = 0;

    unsigned int dateToMonth = 0;
    unsigned int dateToDay = 0;
    unsigned int dateToYear = 0;

    cout << "Enter birth month (1-12): ";
    cin >> birthMonth;
    cout << "Enter birth day (1-31): ";
    cin >> birthDay;
    cout << "Enter birth year (1900 - 2000): ";
    cin >> birthYear;

    Date birthDate (birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear);

    cout << "To which date would you like to calculate to?\nEnter Day month (1-12): ";
    cin >> dateToMonth;
    cout << "Enter Day to calculate it to (1-31): ";
    cin >> dateToDay;
    cout << "Enter Year to calculate it to: ";
    cin >> dateToYear;

    Date dateTo (dateToMonth, dateToDay, dateToYear);

    pastDays(birthDate);
    pastDays(dateTo);

    cout << "\nHow many days ago is the birth date? " << birthDate.old << endl;
    cout << "How many days ago is the secondary date? " << dateTo.old << endl;

}
```

Here is date.h

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class Date
  {
    friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &, const Date & );
public:
    Date( int m = 1, int d = 1, int y = 1900, int o = 0 ); // default constructor
    void setDate( int, int, int, int ); // set month, day, year
//    friend Date operator - (Date &ob1, Date &ob2);
    Date &operator-(); // Modified Line for Assignment
    Date &operator-(Date); // Modified Line for Assignment
    void pastDays (Date);
    static bool leapYear( int ); // is date in a leap year?
    unsigned int month;
    unsigned int day;
    unsigned int year;
    int old;
    static const std::array< unsigned int, 13 > days; // days per month
}; // end class Date

#endif
```

Here is Date.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Date.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Date.h" // Date class definition
using namespace std;

   // initialize static member; one classwide copy
const array< unsigned int, 13 > Date::days = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

// Date constructor
Date::Date( int month, int day, int year, int old )
  {
    setDate( month, day, year, old );
  } // end Date constructor

// set month, day and year
void Date::setDate( int mm, int dd, int yy, int old )
  {
    if ( mm >= 1 && mm <= 12 )
        month = mm;
    else
        throw invalid_argument( "Month must be 1-12" );

    if ( yy >= 1900 && yy <= 2100 )
        year = yy;

    // test for a leap year
//        if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12){
//            if (dd >= 1 || dd <= 31)
//            day == dd;
//        }
//        if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11){
//            if (dd >= 1 || dd <= 30)
//            day == dd;
//        }
//        if (month == 2)
//            if ( year % 4 != 0 ) {
//                if (dd >= 1 || dd <= 29)
//                day == dd;
//            }
//        if (month == 2)
//            if ( year % 4 != 0 ) {
//                if (dd >= 1 || dd <= 28)
//                day == dd;
//            }
//        else {
//            throw invalid_argument(
//                "Day is out of range for current month and year" );
//        }

    if ( ( month == 2 && leapYear( year ) && dd >= 1 && dd <= 29 ) ||
        ( dd >= 1 && dd <= days[ month ] ) )
        day = dd;
    else
        throw invalid_argument(
            "Day is out of range for current month and year" );


} // end function setDate

void pastDays (Date &entryDay) {
    //Creating Today date object
    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm * now = localtime(&t);
    int currentYear = now -> tm_year + 1900;
    int currentMonth = now -> tm_mon + 1;
    int currentDay = now -> tm_mday;

    int birthMonth = entryDay.month;
    int birthDay = entryDay.day;
    int birthYear = entryDay.year;

    //The variable that will be assigned to the old parameter, which can then be subtracted from another time.
    int daysAgo = 0;
    entryDay.old = 0;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "First" << daysAgo << endl;
    cout << "BirthMonth: " << birthMonth << endl;
    cout << "BirthDay: " << birthDay << endl;
    cout << "BirthYear: " << birthYear << endl;

    //Lowering days to 1, to make transition between years easier.
//    while (birthDay > 1){
//        birthDay--;
//        daysAgo--;
//    }

    daysAgo = daysAgo - birthDay;
    daysAgo++;
    birthDay = 1;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Second" << daysAgo << endl;
    cout << "BirthMonth: " << birthMonth << endl;
    cout << "BirthDay: " << birthDay << endl;
    cout << "BirthYear: " << birthYear << endl;

    //Lowering months to 1, to make transition between years easier.
    while (birthMonth > 1){
        if (birthMonth == 1 || birthMonth == 3 || birthMonth == 5 || birthMonth == 7 || birthMonth == 8 || birthMonth == 10 || birthMonth == 12){
            birthMonth--;
            daysAgo -= 31;
        }
        if (birthMonth == 4 || birthMonth == 6 || birthMonth == 9 || birthMonth == 11){
            birthMonth--;
            daysAgo -= 30;
        }
        if (birthMonth == 2)
            if ( currentYear % 400 == 0 ||
            ( currentYear % 100 != 0 && currentYear % 4 == 0 ) ) {
    birthMonth--;
    daysAgo -= 29;
            }
        else {
            birthMonth--;
            daysAgo -= 28;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Third" << daysAgo << endl;
    cout << "BirthMonth: " << birthMonth << endl;
    cout << "BirthDay: " << birthDay << endl;
    cout << "BirthYear: " << birthYear << endl;

    //Incrementing year to current year
    while (birthYear < currentYear){
        if ( currentYear % 400 == 0 ||
        ( currentYear % 100 != 0 && currentYear % 4 == 0 ) ) {
            daysAgo = daysAgo + 366;
            birthYear++;
        }
        else {
            daysAgo = daysAgo + 365;
            birthYear++;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Fourth" << daysAgo << endl;
    cout << "BirthMonth: " << birthMonth << endl;
    cout << "BirthDay: " << birthDay << endl;
    cout << "BirthYear: " << birthYear << endl;

    // Incrementing to current month
    while (birthMonth < currentMonth) {
        if (birthMonth == 1 || birthMonth == 3 || birthMonth == 5 || birthMonth == 7 || birthMonth == 8 || birthMonth == 10 || birthMonth == 12){
            birthMonth++;
            daysAgo += 31;
        }
        if (birthMonth == 4 || birthMonth == 6 || birthMonth == 9 || birthMonth == 11){
            birthMonth++;
            daysAgo += 30;
        }
        if (birthMonth == 2)
            if ( currentYear % 400 == 0 ||
            ( currentYear % 100 != 0 && currentYear % 4 == 0 ) ) {
    birthMonth++;
    daysAgo += 29;
            }
        else {
            birthMonth++;
            daysAgo += 28;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Fifth" << daysAgo << endl;
    cout << "BirthMonth: " << birthMonth << endl;
    cout << "BirthDay: " << birthDay << endl;
    cout << "BirthYear: " << birthYear << endl;

    //Incrementing to current day, and adding the days to the daysAgo
    while (birthDay < currentDay){
        birthDay++;
        daysAgo++;
    }


    cout << endl;
    cout << "Sixth" << daysAgo << endl;
    cout << "BirthMonth: " << birthMonth << endl;
    cout << "BirthDay: " << birthDay << endl;
    cout << "BirthYear: " << birthYear << endl;

    //Assigning DaysAgo to input parameter.old
    entryDay.old = daysAgo;
}


Date operator - (Date &date1, Date &date2)
    {

    Date temp;
    temp.old   = date1.old   - date2.old;
    if(temp.old < 0)
    {
        temp.old = temp.old * -1;
    }
    return(temp);
    }

//Date operator-(Date birthDate)
////friend Distance operator - (Date &birthDate, Date &today)
//    {
////    int birthMonth = birthDate.month;
////    int birthDay = birthDate.day;
////    int birthYear = birthDate.year;
////    int birthOld = 0;
////    Date temp (birthDate.month, birthDate.day, birthDate.year, birthDate.old);
//
////    pastDays(today);
////    pastDays(birthDate);
//
////    int currentMonth = today.month;
////    int currentDay = today.day;
////    int currentYear = today.year;
//
////    int date1 = pastDays(today);
////    int date2 = pastDays(birthDate);
//    Date temp (birthDate.month, birthDate.day, birthDate.year);
//
////    int month, int day, int year, int old
////    temp.month = this -> month;
////    temp.month = this -> day;
////    temp.month = this -> year;
////    Date temp = *this;
//    cout << temp.old;
//
//    temp.old = *this -> old - birthDate.old;
//        //Here I get "Error: Invalid use of 'this' in non-member function;
//
//    return(temp);
//}

bool Date::leapYear( int testYear )
{
    if ( testYear % 400 == 0 ||
      ( testYear % 100 != 0 && testYear % 4 == 0 ) )
        return true; // a leap year
    else
        return false; // not a leap year
} // end function leapYear

// overloaded output operator
ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const Date &d )
{
  static string monthName[ 13 ] = { "", "January", "February",
        "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
        "September", "October", "November", "December" };
  output << monthName[ d.month ] << ' ' << d.day << ", " << d.year;
  return output; // enables cascading
} // end function operator<<
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The structure of `pastDays()` is confusing and strange.**

```
Date::pastDays(birthDate);   --->   birthDate.pastDate(birthDate) // Would compile and maybe work.
                           Change to
Date::pastDays(dateTo);      --->   dateTo.pastDate(dateTo)       // Would compile and maybe work.
```

However, it would be more coherent if you just changed the signature of that function to:

```
void pastDays (Date &entryDay);
```

And **remove** the final `return entryDay` statement as the value is already being passed by reference, so entryDay will be once the function is executed.

So now, in the piece of code where you invoke the function you do not use the scope operator (::) anymore:

```
Date::pastDays(birthDate);   --->   pastDate(birthDate);compile and maybe work.
                           Change to
Date::pastDays(dateTo);      --->   pastDate(dateTo);
```

Comment: @Greg did it help?

Comment: Thank you. I have made the change of the pastDays to become a void. It makes sense, since I didn't declare it as const, that I would be changing the memory values directly, and so now it doesn't need a return type because it is a void. Excellent call.

Back in the main.cpp, I tried changing...

    pastDate(dateTo);
    pastDate(birthDate);

Now it's getting me a "pastDate' was not declared in this scope. 

I thought it would have to be tagged with Date:: so that the program would know where to find it. I'm sorry, I'm just new.

Comment: No prob bud :) Can you mark as correct answer if it helped?

Comment: Heh, I think I am very close, and I think you'll be getting the check once I'm done. ^.^ I did change the Date.h header to not use int anymore, instead it uses void as well, but I am still having a bit of a pickle.